# multiple dom updates in the same function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JavaScript function that takes some time to get executed, from the start to the end of the instructions contained inside. During the execution I would like to display a div element, then after the execution I would like to hide it. I wrote this simple code snippet but doesn't work:

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display: none;" id="d"></div>

<script>

    document.getElementById('d').style.display='block';
    console.log('start');

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.google.com",false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try{
        xmlhttp.send();
    } catch (e) {

    }

    var response = xmlhttp.responseText

    document.getElementById('d').style.display='none';
    console.log('finish');
</script>
```

If you look at the console, you see tat there is an interval between the "start" and the "finish" statement, but the div stays hidden! How is this possible and how to fix it?

Comment: You don't see it because the interval between "start" and "finish" is too small. But I saw it for an instant.

Comment: looking at the console the interval is of 1-2 seconds, but I don't see the div appear on Chrome, it does just on firefox.

Comment: Most browsers won't redraw for every line in the same script, it will only redraw once the browser figures it should etc. Because you have switched of async ajax, which is a big no-no, the browser is now hanging and the thread is locked when the ajax request is done, so the browser doesn't even realize it should redraw, and you never see the element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your life simple with jQuery(http://jquery.com/)
Do the following:
1. Include jQuery to your page
2. Do the following:

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display: none;" id="d"></div>
<script>
    $("#d").show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://www.google.com',

        success: function(data) {
        //code on successful response
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
        // code on error response
        },
        complete:function(){
         // code on  - success/failure
         $("#d").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Enjoy

Comment: The OP doesn't have any problem with AJAX, the question is about how the browser does re–draws during a synchronous request. jQuery is irrelevant for that. Irrelevant answers that probably should have been comments are often down voted. :-/